# A word or expression meaning registering your arrival for an activity?

Tags: expressions

Is there any word or expression in English to talk about a situation when you sign your name to register your arrival for an activity such as a competition or a game? In the corporate environment, we have the expression *clock/punch in* to express a similar concept(but not the same as the one I want). So in a more general sense, which expression or word we can use?

Comment: You "sign up" for it.

Comment: What's wrong with "register"?  A "registration desk" is common at events, conferences, and the like.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer myself. The best choice is *sign in*. This is the definition from the longman dictionary:

> to write your name on a form, in a book etc when you enter a place
>   such as a hotel, office, or club

link to the longman dictionary page: http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sign-in

and the example is as follow:

> Remember to sign in at reception.